# Installing pip on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, macos, pip, macos-sierra

I've been trying to install pip on macOS sierra via brew, but every time it completes without installing the binaries in `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin`.

I've tried:

```
MacBook-Pro ➜ brew reinstall python
```

then:

```
MacBook-Pro ➜  ~ which pip
pip not found
```

I found the path to python, which is `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin` but no binary for pip there.

I also tried the `easy_install` approach:

```
MacBook-Pro ➜ sudo easy_install pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==18.5', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 352, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2307, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2021, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/extension.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .dist import _get_unpatched
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/dist.py", line 21, in <module>
    packaging = pkg_resources.packaging
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packaging'
```

**UPDATE:**

When I run `brew postinstall python` I am getting the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro ➜  ~ brew postinstall python
==> Using the sandbox
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --rec
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --rec
Last 15 lines from /Users/justin/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python/post_install.02.python:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 92, in <module>
    cmdclass={'test': PyTest},
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/Users/justin/.venvburrito/lib/python/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/Users/justin/.venvburrito/lib/python/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 258, in finalize_options
    ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
  File "/Users/justin/.venvburrito/lib/python/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2020, in load
    raise ImportError("%r has no %r attribute" % (entry,attr))
ImportError: <module 'setuptools.dist' from '/Users/justin/.venvburrito/lib/python/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.pyc'> has no 'check_specifier' attribute
```

Comment: `sudo easy_install` does not put pip into the brew directory

Comment: Does `pip2` exist?

Comment: @cricket_007 no `pip` or `pip2` in `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin`.

Answer (score 48):

You just need to install `pip` which is not automatically installed in macOS Sierra.

Run `sudo easy_install pip`

Comment: Worked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 18):

For Mac OS Sierra, cannot install pip via `easy_install` since there is a problem with TLS Version, Installed Open-SSL version won't support TLS 1.2

So install pip using curl as follows,

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python
```

Comment: I can confirm that this single command worked like a charm on MacOS Sierra v10.12.5!!  Other single commands to do it each failed in different ways. Thanks!!

Comment: Worked for me in Catalina as well.

Answer (score 5):

OK gang, lots of these answers where helpful but none of them got  me to the finish line.  I am running High Sierra 10.13.4.  The problem as documented above is that Brew installs pip in the `/usr/local/bin` directory but Python is in `/usr/bin` (although as Carl said, Python3 correctly goes to `/usr/local/bin`).

My immediate use case is related to getting the [Postgres BigSQL](http://www.openscg.com/bigsql/postgresql/installers/) package to install.

The steps I took are as follows:

1. Clear out the brew cache `$ rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew`
2. Clear out the site-packages `$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
3. Reinstall Python `$ brew reinstall python` This pulls down `python-3.5.6.high_sierra` and put it in `/usr/local/bin/python3`
4. But `which python` still shows `/usr/bin/python`
5. The **solution** is to run `brew install python@2` which pulls down `python@2-2.7.14_3.high_sierra`
6. Now `which python` shows the correct path `/usr/local/bin/python` which is also where all your pip stuff is installed, so now pip will work.
7. Of course if you have not installed the latest version of pip you should do that too with `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 4):

Something must be wrong with your brew installation.

Latest macOS version.

```
 ~/ brew reinstall python
==> Reinstalling python
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/python-2.7.13.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.13.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring python-2.7.13.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Using the sandbox
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7
==> Caveats
Pip and setuptools have been installed. To update them
  pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

You can install Python packages with
  pip install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

See: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Homebrew-and-Python.md

.app bundles were installed.
Run `brew linkapps python` to symlink these to /Applications.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13: 3,526 files, 48M
```

And it definitely exists.

```
 ~/ ls -l $(which pip)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 cricket  admin  31 Dec 19 19:43 /usr/local/bin/pip -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/pip
```

Comment: Ok, when I run `brew postinstall python` I am getting errors. See original question for update.

Comment: Not sure why you need to run that, but it works fine for me. Try deleting the cached file at `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew`

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and I found this to be the solution. BTW pip isn't installed via brew.  It comes with python and python virtualenvs.

if you type `which python` without `brew install python` you'll get the location in `/usr/bin/python`.  That is the system python which we don't want to develop with.

So i took the following steps.
1) `brew install python`
2) `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"` place that in your `~/.bash_profile`
3) `source ~/.bash_profile` in your terminal
4)  type `which python` and that should have changed the location to `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python`.

This will allow you to pip install normally and use the brew version of python.

Now before high sierra python used to be located in `/usr/local/bin` but for some reason if you place `/usr/local/bin` in your paths it automatically points back to `/usr/bin`, so this is the only solution I have been able to come up with.

Python3 does not have this issue, if you `brew install python3` and type `which python3` you'll see that it's located in `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, after upgrading to high sierra I found my machine pretty much unusable for development, even crashing plenty of times.

Regarding python, i had a rights issue inside the site-packages folder, therefore the reinstall did not work out:

```
$ brew reinstall python

==> Reinstalling python
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/python-2.7.14.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/m/Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.14.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring python-2.7.14.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/bin/python2 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/bin --install-
Last 15 lines from /Users/m/Library/Logs/Homebrew/python/post_install.01.python2:
.
.
.
copying build/lib/setuptools/script (dev).tmpl -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools
copying build/lib/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging
error: could not delete '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py': Permission denied
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
...
```

So to fix it, I completely removed the site-packages:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

With this, reinstalling python2, and having a working pip2 again, worked like a charm:

```
$ brew reinstall python

$ which pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2
$ which python2
/usr/local/bin/python2

$ which pip
pip not found
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error message has the answer for you...

Remove `/Users/justin/.venvburrito/lib/python/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg/` and run `brew reinstall python`. `setuptools` is the wrong version.